# Paginacion en laravel no funciona siguiente

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, paginación

Estoy buscando como resolver este inconveniente  y no consigo dar con la solución.
En mi localhost funciona perfecto pero en el servidor compartido no anda. Supongo que debe ser un problema del htaccess pero probé varias cosas y siguen sin funcionar.

El problema está en la paginación, al hacer clic en siguiente vuelve a mostrar la misma pagina no la siguiente.

En mi blade:

```
<div class="col-md-8">

            @foreach($posts as $post)

            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{{ route('post', $post->slug) }}">
                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h1>{{ $post->name }}</h1>
                    </div>


                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if ($post->file)
                            <img src="{{ url($post->file) }}" class="card-img-top img-responsive effectShadow zoomIn" alt="Imagen del Post">
                        @endif
                        <br><br>
                        <span style="font-size: 25px;">{{ $post->excerpt }}</span>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="float: left;"><i style="color: #9a9797;" class="fas fa-sign"></i> {{ $post->category->name }}</span> <br>
                        <span style="font-size: 15px;"><i style="color: #9a9797;" class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                        <span style="float: right;">Leer más <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span> 
                    </div>

                </div>

            </a>

            <br>

            @endforeach

            <!-- $posts = Colección completa. el método render agrega la paginación -->
            {{ $posts->render() }}

        </div>
```

El controlador:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->paginate(3);
        return view('web/posts', compact('posts', 'categoriasFiltradas', 'etiquetas', 'ultimosPosts'));
```

y el htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'Web\PaginaWebController@index');
Route::get('mensaje', 'Web\PaginaWebController@store');

Auth::routes();

// VERIFICACIÓN DE MAIL
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

// WEB
Route::get('/libro', 'Web\LibroController@index');
Route::get('/SobreMi', 'SobreController@index');
Route::resource('contacto', 'ContactoController');


// BLOG
Route::get('/comunidad', 'Web\PageController@blog')->name('comunidad');
Route::get('entrada/{slug}', 'Web\PageController@post')->name('post');
Route::get('categoria/{slug}', 'Web\PageController@category')->name('category');
Route::get('etiqueta/{slug}', 'Web\PageController@tag')->name('tag');
Route::get('buscar', 'Web\PageController@buscador');
```

Probé agregando varias opciones en htaccess pero sin efecto. Agradecería mucho que me puedan brindar una orientación.

Comment: parece ser un simple error de ruta, deberias de mostrar tus rutas.

Comment: Agregue las rutas, efectivamente hay un problema en mi servidor compartido. En localhost me funciona y la ruta es asi: localhost:8000/comunidad?page=2 en cambio en el servidor me agrega la barra / https://martinaquino.com/comunidad/?page=2. Que podría agregarme esa barra?

Comment: Ninguna sugerencia?

Comment: @Martinaet revertí tu edición, la solución no va en la pregunta, por favor considera publicarla en la zona de respuestas